# How to make a selector 'live' so it works on newly inserted DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do this:

```
$(".someClass").datepicker();
```

But the DOM or the  with this class gets dynamically inserted into the page when someone clicks on a button, so this is the reason I'm guessing the above code isn't working.

How can I get this to work with newly inserted elements into the page AFTER it loads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".someClass").live('yourTrigger',function(){

// your logic here
//$(".someClass").datePicker():

});
```

Comment: Funny, because there's `live` in the question subject too. :)

Comment: well, yes, but the whole point is what is 'yourCustomTrigger'; we want it to be 'create', but that is not a valid event ;(

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload=function(){
    $(".someClass").datepicker();
}
```

Comment: Looks like somebody beat me to it. Could the question be any more ambiguous?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), or simply call that line in the existing handler that creates element(s) and/or assigns `someClass` to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#updateSomeOfTheDom").live("click", function() {

    // init the datepicker in $.load, $.get or $.post's callback
    $("#section").load('/update.html', function(response) {
        $(response).find('.someClass').datePicker();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can only hook to certain events on an element, but bizarrely their inclusion in the dom is not an event. although I find this puzzling, there is a simple solution with

```
$(".someClass").livequery(function() { $(this).datepicker();});
```

after you install this plugin
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery

Alternatively I found this:

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-create-event/

https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-create-event

or its most recent fork

https://github.com/yumok/jquery-create-event